¿Qué tengo mal en la sentencia preparada para que me dé el error?
Estoy intentando convertir una consulta a una base de datos a sentencia preparada, pero me da un error y no sé a qué se debe ese error. El error que  me da es:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number.

En primer lugar pongo la sentencia que me funciona perfectamente:
public function getVacaciones_(string $id, string $año, string $tipo){
  try{
$consulta = $this->conectar->query("SELECT * FROM vacaciones WHERE DNI='$id' AND Tipo='$tipo' AND YEAR(Fecha_Inicio)=$año AND YEAR(Fecha_Fin)=$año");                
                $resultado = $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);                               
return $resultado;
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                throw new Exception("Error de consulta: "- $e->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

Y ahora la consulta con sentencia preparada
public function getVacaciones(string $id, string $año, string $tipo){
            try{

                $this->strDNI = $id;                
                $this->strFechaAlta = $año;
                $this->intTipo = $tipo;                
                $consulta = "SELECT * FROM vacaciones WHERE DNI=:dni AND Tipo=:tipo AND YEAR(Fecha_Inicio)=:año AND YEAR(Fecha_Fin)=:año";                
                $insert = $this->conectar->prepare($consulta);
                $insert->bindParam(":dni", $this->strDNI);                                
                $insert->bindParam(":tipo", $this->intTipo);
                $insert->bindParam(":año", $this->strFechaAlta);                
                $insert->execute();
                $resultado = $insert->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                print_r($resultado); exit;
                return $resultado;

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                throw new Exception("Error de consulta: " .$e->getMessage());
            }
        }


Y que tipo de parámetros estas mandando??

Da la sensacion de que tienes :año dos veces en la definición de la sentencia. Según esto eso no es posible. Prueba a poner :añoInicio y :añoFin y haz un bindParam para cada uno, aunque a los dos les asignes $año

No es necesario anteponer el tipo de variable al nombre de la variable. Por ejemplo, podrías nombrar "strDNI" simplemente como "DNI".   Especialmente porque nunca agregaste el tipo a ninguna otra variable como $consulta, $resultado y $e.   El estilo consistente es importante.  Y creo que podrías usar $id, $tipo y $año directamente con bindParam() (como tu primero ejemplo) y eliminar las otras variables.

Si vas a cambiar más de una query yo haría algo más escalable...

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

El error que nos muestras: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number ...  indica que hay un problema con la asignación de parámetros en la consulta preparada. Este error te sale cuando la cantidad de parámetros vinculados no coincide con la cantidad de parámetros esperados en la consulta.
En tu código, el problema parece estar relacionado con el parámetro :año, que se utiliza dos veces en la consulta, pero solo se vincula una vez. PDO no permite la reutilización directa de parámetros en la consulta preparada. Tendrás que definir dos parámetros diferentes para cada aparición de :año.
En este caso yo sugeriria cambiar un poco el script para evitar este erro de la siguiente forma:
public function getVacaciones(string $id, string $año, string $tipo) {
    try {
        $this->strDNI = $id;
        $this->strFechaAlta = $año;
        $this->intTipo = $tipo;

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM vacaciones WHERE DNI=:dni AND Tipo=:tipo AND YEAR(Fecha_Inicio)=:año_inicio AND YEAR(Fecha_Fin)=:año_fin";
        $insert = $this->conectar->prepare($consulta);

        $insert->bindParam(":dni", $this->strDNI);
        $insert->bindParam(":tipo", $this->intTipo);
        $insert->bindParam(":año_inicio", $this->strFechaAlta);
        $insert->bindParam(":año_fin", $this->strFechaAlta);

        $insert->execute();
        $resultado = $insert->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        
        // Esta seccion sumo que es de prueba...
        print_r($resultado); 
        exit;

        // Este es el return que deberia funcionar sin la impresion de prueba...
        return $resultado;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception("Error de consulta: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

Estos son los cambios relizados, que corrigen el problema:

Renombré :año a :año_inicio y :año_fin para que coincidan con los dos lugares en los que se usa en la consulta.
Vinculé :año_inicio y :año_fin por separado usando bindParam a $this->strFechaAlta esta propiedad puede ser utilizada facilmente y sin problemas 2 veces.

